# Filtering on factor variable using double variable in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How come I can filter a factor variable using a double variable in one case, but not in another?

Example data below:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:9,
                 var=factor(81:89))

# > dt
#    id var
# 1:  1  81
# 2:  2  82
# 3:  3  83
# 4:  4  84
# 5:  5  85
# 6:  6  86
# 7:  7  87
# 8:  8  88
# 9:  9  89
```

Why does this work...

```
dt[id %in% 1:7 & var %in% c(82, 84)]

#    id var
# 1:  2  82
# 2:  4  84
```

...but this gives an error?

```
dt[var %in% c(82, 84)]

# Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- FALSE, xo, roll = 0,  : 
#  x.'var' is a factor column being joined to i.'V1' which is type 'double'.
# Factor columns must join to factor or character columns.`
```

Seems a bit inconsequent and might be a bug?

Comment: I'm getting the correct output ....

Comment: I am getting the same error: R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03), data.table_1.9.6

Comment: Please add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post. Looks like this is fixed in data.table_1.9.7.

Comment: I'm using *data.table 1.9.7*

Comment: Was indeed using data.table version 1.9.6, looks like this was already fixed in 1.9.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that the second example is optimized by automatic indexing, which throws this error. You can switch off this feature like this:

```
dt[(var %in% c(82, 84))]
#   id var
#1:  2  82
#2:  4  84
```

Then a base R vector scan is used and usual coercion rules apply. From `help("%in%")`:

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and
>   then x and table are coerced to a common type

```
var <- factor(81:89)
var %in% c(82, 84)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The problem has been [fixed](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/405f1156feacc9713f619a2796f2ac03321900c5) in data.table version 1.9.7.